# How tor write a query to perform two different selection from same table

Tags: mysql, spring-data-jpa

I am working on a table that is similar to stack overflow. It stores questions answers and comments.

I tried to create a query that retrieves data in the following way. A question and its comments and answer for this question and comments for the answer.

I don't know how to retrieve all this information from the same table. If they were in different tables, it would be easy. I tried inner join and using sub-query but they didn't give me the correct output.

I want to use this query in spring-data-jpa. First, I tried to make it with jpa but it doesn't work. I think this query is more complex to create it directly with spring-data-jpa.

these are the important fields of my table in MySQL:

```
id | content_id | content_type_id | subject | body | tags | user_id | dtype
```

content_id is using for answers and comments and shows the id of a question that answer or comment belongs to. dtype specify the type of record it has one of the Question, Answer or Comment values.

these are queries that I tried:

```
select distinct T1.`content_id`,
(Select `body`,`dtype` from content As T3 where T3.content_id = 19 and 
T3.content_type_id = 2),
(Select `body`,`dtype` from content As T4 where T4.content_type_id = 3 and 
T4.content_id = T3.id)
from content as T1

SELECT a.body, a.user_id, a.dtype, c.body, c.user_id, c.dtype FROM content a
JOIN content c ON a.id = c.content_id WHERE a.content_id = 19
```

this is the method that I tried to use in spring boot

```
public Question getQuestionAnswerAndComment(Question question){
    List<List> result = new ArrayList<>();
    Optional<Question> ques = getQuestion(question); // getting one question by id

    result.add(questionRepository.findByContentTypeIdAndContentId(3, question.getId()));  //getting comments of the question (3 means comment)
    Answer ans = questionRepository.findByContentTypeIdAndContentIdAnswer(2, question.getId()); // getting answers of the question (2 measn answer)
}
```

the problem here is the third method call that selects all the answers for a question and return a list so I can't use its output to find comments for a specific answer.

now what should I do to achieve my desired data from database, I should use spring-data-jpa methods or create a custom query and then call it.

Desired result:

Question

----Comments of the question

The first answer to the question

----Comments of the first answer

The second answer to the question

----Comments of the second answer

Comment: 'if they were indifferent tables it would be easy' *might just hint at* you needing to revise the data model

Comment: but I can't because it is a table that whole project work on it

Comment: The SQL tables should be abstracted in several Java classes. For understanding the matter, posting those classes would be a helpful first step.

Comment: I'm not clear on what you want to get from this. A list with all the relevant rows from the table? Or an object (`Question`) with references to comments and answers which themselves have references to further comments?

Comment: why do your queries limit on a specific `content_id`? What is the meaning of `content_id =19`?

Answer (score 0):

I would start with a select like the following which should select all the data that belongs to a question along with it in consecutive rows.

```
select * from content as questions
    left join content as comment_or_answer
        on questions.id = comment_or_answer.content_id
    left join content as answer_comments
        on comment_or_answer.id = answer_comments.content_id
where questions.content_type_id = <question-type-id>
    and <add constraints on the question here, e.g. on the id>
order by questions.id, comment_or_answer.content_type_id, comment_or_answer.id
```

This gives you a threefold join of the table with questions in the first set of columns, comment and answers in the second set of columns and comments to answers in the third set of columns.

I then would execute that query using a `NamedParameterJdbcTemplate` and use a `ResultSetExtractor` to construct a result object from it.